# WordPress Thesis theme - hook below post

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-thesis-theme

i need a little help with thesis theme, i made a simple hook for single post with custom content and i want the hook to be right after the post but after the post there's a plugins like facebook etc...   and my hook is below that.   How to make my hook to be right after post without disabling this plugins ?

*i already tried every posible combinations thesis_hook_after_post, thesis_hook_after_post_box etc and it dont work

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Change priority value in [add_action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action)

```
add_action( $tag, $function_to_add, $priority, $accepted_args );
```

> (int) (optional) Used to specify the order in which the functions
>   associated with a particular action are executed. **Lower numbers
>   correspond with earlier execution**, and functions with the same
>   priority are executed in the order in which they were added to the
>   action. Default: 10

Edit:-

```
 function post_article111() { 
   if (is_single( )) {  
    echo "content goes here.."; 
    }
 } 

add_action('thesis_hook_after_post_box', 'post_article111','5');
```

Comment: i tried now all posible combinations with priority and it dont't work.

can you please write me code with $priority included, maybe i made mistake somewhere


function post_article111() {

if (is_single( )) { ?>

content goes here

<?php }}
add_action('thesis_hook_after_post_box', 'post_article111');

Thanks in advance